# Core data managed var seems to be initialised instead of nil

Tags: core-data, null, init, nsset

I have a core data class with this var:

```
@NSManaged var tags: NSSet?
```

The issue is that when the class is fetched from the data store, the tags variable instead of being nil, is initialised with an empty NSSet object.

Does this behaviour normal?

I thought it will be nil.

**Update and question:**
I checked with the behaviour of a core data Attribute, and it is nil after the fetch.

Is it possible that for Relationships, which is NSSet/NSOrderedSet, core data doesn't use nil, but initialised an empty set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core Data uses faulting:

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/FaultingandUniquing.html)

Essentially what happens here is:

> A managed object fault is an instance of the appropriate class, but its persistent variables are not yet initialized.
>
> A relationship fault is a subclass of the collection class that represents the relationship.

So you might have an instance of a set but you won't know what the persisten value is until you accessed it.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Ron. So it seems that I must check for the length of the set, instead of nil, in cases like mine. And for managed objects I must check for "isFault". Is this right?

Comment: @Shay you should never have to call is fault directly. Once you access a relationship on a managed object, the fault should fire and resolve it. So count would work to know how many tags there are.

Comment: If you just want to count the tags before fetching them, you could use  a countForFetchRequest or an NSManagedObjectContext https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSManagedObjectContext/countForFetchRequest:error:

Comment: So how should i approach managed objects vars and not sets? I can't use count for them in order to know if they actually exists, if the object won't be nil. At the docs that you put, it said " If you retrieve just a single Employee object from a persistent store, its manager, department, and reports relationships are initially represented by faults." If I can't check for nil this is an issue. If the optional unbound will be true, like with that tags, this is bad. I can say that I did a test, and optional unbending for object was false, that I was happy to see. But is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: One thing to assure this is to set the relationshipKeypathsForPrefetching. This way you'll guarantee that once your object is resolved, it's relationships are too. Then checking for nil should be ok in any case. Since faults will be resolved already

Comment: Is this doesn't abuse the purpose of fault? When Apple recommend to use it?

Comment: Don't think so. You can cherry pick. It's an option. If you wouldn't prefetch , then the data will be pulled in on access of the property. Depends on what you need.